# Auto trigger function throuigh service in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

hi all i am using `angulrajs` passing one value from one `controller` to another controller using service it's work fine but my need is when service value change in `controller 2` i get the service value in one scope when scope value change i need trigger the function it's called `refresh` function when `service` value change and that i need to call the refresh function here my fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/ctawL4t3/10/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just `$watch` your `value.storeObject`. Though it's not best of the practices, but it suits this kind of feature.

```
$scope.$watch('value.storedObject', function(newVal) {
  if(newVal !== '') {
    refresh()
  }
})
```

[**working fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/dy87pbav/) (open console to see `refresh` function logging)

Comment: hi tanmay after page refreshing service value change to null but i need last typed value

Comment: @jose you can utilize `localStorage` for that inside your refresh or `ng-change` depending on where you want to do it.. it's fairly simple to use.. check out [localStorage docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)

Comment: using localstorage means it'wont delete?

Comment: @jose it means it will be present on page reload, read docs on how to store and then access it.. it's totally easy to use

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43850413/how-to-get-the-value-even-page-reload-in-angularjs
@tanmay

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use angular default `$emit`, `$broadcast`, or try to do 2 simple functions in own service

```
angular.module('app').factory('StoreService', function() {

  var listeners = {};

  var emit = function(name, val) {
     if(listeners[name]) {
        listeners[name](val)
     }
  }

  var on = function(name, callback) {
       listeners[name] = callback;
  }

  return {
    emit: emit,
    on: on,
    storedObject: ''
  };
});
```

JSFiddle [example](https://jsfiddle.net/yenoftz5/)

JSFiddle [example](https://jsfiddle.net/yenoftz5/2/) `$watch`

JSFiddle [example](https://jsfiddle.net/yenoftz5/3/) `ng-change` is better because, you can use easily `debounce`

Comment: it's working but when button click then only function trigger my need is when  controller 1 value changed automatically refresh function will be call help how to do this

Comment: I updated my answer. You can attach it on `ng-change` directive or use `$watch`

Answer (score 0):

you can use broadcast function for that
Please check this SO link to find the related answer

[How to call a function from another controller in angularjs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29467339/how-to-call-a-function-from-another-controller-in-angularjs)

```
app.controller('One', ['$scope', '$rootScope'
    function($scope) {
        $rootScope.$on("CallParentMethod", function(){
           $scope.parentmethod();
        });

        $scope.parentmethod = function() {
            // task
        }
    }
]);
app.controller('two', ['$scope', '$rootScope'
    function($scope) {
        $scope.childmethod = function() {
            $rootScope.$emit("CallParentMethod", {});
        }
    }
]);
```

Comment: i need to work on service @Nair Athul.if possible kindly update my fiddle