# how to get the value even page reload in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, service

hi all iam using angularjs service move data from one controller to another controller when i change dropdown i store value into service and bind the table through this service in another controller it's works fine but my need is after page reloading service value should be turn to null but i need last selected value even i stored into cookies but it's shows null help how to do this

## service code

```
app.factory('StoreService', function() {
  return {
    storedObject:''
  };

});


 
app.controller('name', ['$scope', '$http', '$window', '$filter', '$cookieStore','StoreService', 
 function ($scope, $http, $window, $filter, $cookieStore,StoreService) {
    
  $scope.FacilityChange=function(){
        debugger;
            $scope.value = StoreService;
            
           
    };
});
```

## Html

```
   <select id="MaterialFacility"  
               form="DistanceMatrixFormId" class="form-control"   
                 ng-change="FacilityChange(value.storedObject)"
             ng-model="value.storedObject" >
                                           
        <option value=''>Select</option>
        <option value=0>0</option>
        <option value=1>1</option>
                                                       
   </select>
```

Comment: `last selected value even i stored into cookies but it's shows null`

Can you show your cookie code?

Comment: You should use `$cookies` instead `$cookieStore`